# vagrant-berkshelf plugin compilation (installation) error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra, vagrant, berkshelf

enclosed a snippet of my console:

**release version:**

```
$ sudo cat /etc/*release* | grep -i distrib
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=saucy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 13.10"
```

**ruby version:**

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p299 (2013-08-29) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

**vagrant version:**

```
$ vagrant --version
Vagrant 1.3.5
```

**prerequisites:**

```
$ sudo dpkg -s libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libxslt1.1 build-essential | grep -i status
Status: install ok installed
Status: install ok installed
Status: install ok installed
Status: install ok installed
Status: install ok installed
```

when i try to install `vagrant-berkshelf` plugin, i receive the following **error:**

```
$ sudo vagrant plugin install vagrant-berkshelf --plugin-version 1.3.4
Installing the 'vagrant-berkshelf --version '1.3.4'' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:562:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

        /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.8.0... ERROR, review 'tmp/x86_64-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.8.0/compile.log' to see what happened.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby
/home/user/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:265:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
    from /home/user/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:257:in `chdir'
    from /home/user/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:257:in `execute'
    from /home/user/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:69:in `compile'
    from /home/user/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:109:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:101:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:119:in `call'
    from extconf.rb:119:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:109:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:109:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /home/user/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/user/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:540:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:515:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:515:in `build_extensions'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:180:in `install'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:297:in `block in install'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `each_with_index'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `install'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:49:in `block in call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/gem_helper.rb:42:in `block in with_environment'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:40:in `use_ui'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/gem_helper.rb:41:in `with_environment'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:39:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/action/bundler_check.rb:20:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/command/base.rb:17:in `action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:27:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/plugins/commands/plugin/command/root.rb:52:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:38:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:478:in `cli'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.5/bin/vagrant:96:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in `load'
    from /opt/vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in `<main>'
```

can someone help me solve the issue

**update:**
the same error holds for `vagrant-berkshelf` version 1.3.x, 1.2.0, and even without specifying the version explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

investigation reveals that `zlib` is missing, so compilation fails. executing the following should solve your problem.

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev lib64z1-dev
sudo vagrant plugin install vagrant-berkshelf --plugin-version 1.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 vagrant plugin install vagrant-berkshelf
```

[Source](https://github.com/berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/issues/109)

Comment: i got to the link when i was searching a solution before posting here. anyhow, same erroneous result (even when executing as a `sudo`).